# Сложный обрис

Tags: android, canvas, graphics

Рисую вот такой shape:

```
Paint pt = new Paint();
pt.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
pt.setStrokeWidth(2);
pt.setColor(Color.GREEN);

Path path = new Path();         
path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.lineTo(40, 0);
path.lineTo(40, 10);
path.addArc(new RectF(30, 10, 50, 30), -90, 180);
path.lineTo(40, 40);
path.lineTo(30, 40);
path.addArc(new RectF(10, 30, 30, 50), 0, 180);
path.lineTo(0, 40);
path.lineTo(0, 0);

path.close();       
canvas.drawPath(path, pt);
```

Почему-то соединяется начало второй дуги и стартовая точка. Как этого можно избежать? К сожалению изображение выложить не могу, т.к. репутация низкая.

Comment: Раз вопрос неактуален, то закройте его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, проблема решена. Просто вместо метода drawArc использовал метод arcTo.